# pass array from vue.js to laravel controller, Error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem when trying to pass an array from vue.js to a laravel controller, the problem is that the route tells me that it is get but I have it as a post...
sorry for my bad english.

```
   const create = new Vue({
    el: '#createRemitos',
    data:{
        remitos:[]
    },
    methods:{
        deleteElement:function(){
           this.remitos.pop();
        },
        saveRemito: function(){
            var url ='make/create';
            axios.post(url,{
                remitos: this.remitos
            }).then(response => {
                //toastr.success('Guardado');
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch(e =>{
                toastr.error('Error');
            });
        }
    }
});

//this is my route.

Route::post('/make/create','CreateRemitoController@create')->name('create.store');

//this is my controller

public function create(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing absolute and relative URLs.

change from:

```
var url ='make/create';
```

to:

```
var url ='/make/create';
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass route name instead passing url :

```
var url ='make/create';
```

become:

```
var url ='{{route("create.store")}}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem was an error of mine I did not know how to use axios the code I leave it for future reference is 100% functional thanks to the people who helped me.